# How to Change vite application port

Tags: reactjs, port, vite

If you are change the vite application port please follow the procedure.

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "vite --port 3006",
  "build": "vite build",
  "preview": "vite preview"
}
```

Comment: Is this an answer or a question?

Answer (score 54):

Try add your port  into vite.config.ts:

```
 export default defineConfig({
  // ...some configs
  server: {
    port: 3006,
  },
});
```

Comment: I created the file but is not working

Comment: @Caeta make sure to run just `vite` and not `vite preview`. `vite preview` does not look at that setting.

Comment: @Caeta just to clarify, `vite preview` looks at `preview`, which is the identical config format to `server`

Answer (score 6):

you can modify the dev script in the `package.json` file and set the `--port` to the one you want .

[image]

Answer (score 3):

in vite.config.ts you can manage the port separately for production and development. PORT server: production. PORT preview: development

```
export default defineConfig({
//change port for production
  preview: {
    port: 3001,
  },
// for dev
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [defining it in the config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77672330/2860309) or [providing it on the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73451953/2860309), it's also possible to configure the port in `.env` files - anything in `.env` / `.env.production` etc that's prefixed with `VITE_` will be automatically available to your app via `import.meta.env` and can be loaded into the `vite.config.ts` file using `loadEnv`:

```js
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { ConfigEnv, defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig(({command, mode} : ConfigEnv) => {
    console.log(`configuring vite with command: ${command}, mode: ${mode}`);
    // suppress eslint warning that process isn't defined (it is)
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    const cwd = process.cwd();
    console.log(`loading envs from ${cwd} ...`);
    const env = {...loadEnv(mode, cwd, 'VITE_')};
    console.log(`loaded env: ${JSON.stringify(env)}`);

    // reusable config for both server and preview
    const serverConfig = {
        host: true,
        port: Number(env.VITE_PORT),
        strictPort: true,
    };

    return {
        base: '/',
        plugins: [react()],
        preview: serverConfig,
        server: serverConfig,
    };
});
```